# open separate browser window and pass data

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I want to display some data in a separate browser window instead of using popupManager. How do i do that. Also i need to pass parameter to that window, based on that parameter, i ll call the service and get the required data and display that in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [navigateToURL()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()) and possibly the [external interface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=19_External_Interface_04.html).  You should be able to just pass url parameters to provide information to the other window.